# What is the XQuery equivalent of the ESQL COALESCE function?

Tags: sql, xquery, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I'm trying convert WMB 7 mapping nodes to IIB 9 nodes. The auto-convert process turns some ESQL functions to XQuery functions.

Specifically, it turns the ESQL function

```
COALESCE (var0, var1)
```

(which returns the first non-null value, as in `if var0 = null then var1 else var0`) into

```
XQUERY (var0,var1)
```

1. Is it a correct conversion?
2. If it is, can someone provide a link to API? I couldn't find this on XQuery syntax and operators manuals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XQuery is not an API, but a standard, and the full syntax can be found online: [XQuery 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/) and [XQuery 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-3/) (there is no 2.0). You'll also find many manuals, tutorials etc.

XQuery relies on [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/), which is even wider used than XQuery and can be found in libraries for almost every general purpose language.

Your expression is correct XQuery, in that it considers everything a sequence, and the comma concatenates (and flattens) two sequences.

XPath does not know `NULL`, but it knows `xsi:nil` and `()`, the latter being the *empty sequence*. An empty sequence is removed from the result.

I am not sure what XQuery processor is used underneath, but the correct expression should be `($var0, $var1)[1]`<sup>2</sup>, which works the same way as your `COALESCE` operation<sup>1</sup>. In XPath and XQuery, variables are referenced with the `$` sign. The number of variables or expressions separated by the comma is unbounded. If all are the empty sequence (null), the result is the empty sequence.

Without `[1]`, it will return all items that are non-null and discard the rest. You can use another index, like `[3]` to get the third non-null value. If no such value exists, it will return null (empty sequence).

---

<sup>1</sup> *which behaves not exactly the way you described it. I believe it behaves like `if var0 == null then var1 else var0`, it selects the first non-null value (I've updated the OP).*

<sup>2</sup> *as Florent has explained in the comments, a warning with this expression is in place. If you have `$var1 := (1, 2)` and `$var2 := (3, 4)`, the expression `$var1, $var2)[1]` will return `1`, not `(1, 2)`, because sequences cannot contain subsequences, and indexing a sequence with `[x]` will return the x<sup>th</sup> value of the flattened sequence. You can safe-guard your expression with `(zero-or-one($var1), zero-or-one($var2))[1]`.*

Comment: I know I wasn't accurate when describing COALESCE, I was aiming for simplecity.

Comment: np, I was familiar with it, most sql variants have it. Note that in XPath sequences are ordered and cannot contain subsequences (flattened) and can have any length. So, `($a, $b, $c, $d, $e)[1]` will return the first of the five that is non-null, and without `[1]`, it will return all of them that are non-null (q. updated).

Comment: I use this idiom a lot (that is, `(a,b)[1]`). But you have to be **very** careful that `a` and `b` contain each 0 or 1 item. If not, this expression will silently ignore all but the first item. So use it only when you declared the cardinality of the variable, using `?`. If not, using `fn:zero-or-one()` or using the full-fledged `if-then-else` is safer.

Comment: @FlorentGeorges agreed, a warning is in place, I have updated the answer with your suggestions :)

Comment: Well, I am not sure your example if the less confusing one :-) There is no such thing as `((), 2)`. Maybe a better example is with `(1, 2)` and `(3, 4)`, and a warning that `($a, $b)[1]` returns `1` only (as the first item in `(1, 2, 3, 4)`), rather than the full value of `$a` (because there is no embedded sequences, and they are "flattened"...

Comment: @FlorentGeorges, if I understand the req's correctly, the OP uses sequences that can contain null (empty sequence), hence `((), 2)`, which is valid syntax, but will effectively be `2`. But I agree (and digress). I've updated with your example ;).